# .bashrc not working after restart

Tags: 12.04, bashrc

I can't figure out what's wrong with my PC! I'm quite new to Ubuntu.

I need to add android tools to the PATH variable so I add the following lines to .bashrc file:

```
PATH=${PATH}:/home/user/Program\ Files/android-sdks/platform-tools:/home/user/Program\ Files/android-sdks/tools
```

after that I run `source .bashrc` and when I run `echo $PATH` the android tools shows up in the `$PATH` variable.

But when I logout android tools are gone from the `$PATH` variable and I have to run `source .bashrc` to load them again there. Any ideas why is it happening?

Comment: can you edit your question to include the output of the command:  echo $SHELL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your ~/.profile (or ~/.bash_profile, whichever is present):

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: May I suggest `[[ -r ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc` instead ? Purely a personal preferences of course. :')

Comment: Yes, that's better.